# How to move label next to the associated fields with flexbox

Tags: html, css

I want to move the labels next to the associated elements with flexbox. I tried different ways but I can yet not work well with flexbox therefore I want to learn it. The label should look like the label in the following picture.

[image: label next to input field].

Is it necessary to build your own class for the labels and set extra flexbox settings for those or is it possible to position the labels within the class of the boxes?

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Padauk', sans-serif;
}

#heading {
  color: rgba(130, 195, 236, 1);
}

#boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30vh;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 30px;
}

#boxes>*:nth-child(4) {
  margin-top: 1vh;
}

#boxes>*:nth-child(5) {
  margin-top: -1vh;
}

.input {
  background-color: rgba(152, 187, 209, 0.386);
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: rgba(130, 195, 236, 1);
}

.box {
  width: 31vh;
  height: 5vh;
  text-align: center;
}

#output-box {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-color: rgb(10, 126, 179);
  background-color: rgba(64, 143, 193, 0.453);
  color: rgba(29, 2, 54, 0.311);
}

::placeholder {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.232);
}

#button {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(152, 187, 209, 0.386);
  border-color: rgba(130, 195, 236, 1);
  color: rgba(52, 160, 228, 0.588);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(130, 195, 236, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxes">
  <h1 id="heading"> Taximeter</h1>
  <input oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" min="0" placeholder="How far is your target?" id="input-box1" class="box input" type="number">

  <input min="0" max="4" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" min="0" placeholder="How many people are driving with you?" id="input-box2" class="box input" type="number">

  <output class="box" id="output-box"></output>

  <button onclick="calci()" id="button"> calculate!</button>
</div>

<div class="labels">
  <label class="labels" id="km" for="input-box1">km</label>
  <label class="labels" id="personen" for="input-box2"> Passengers </label>
  <label class="labels" id="Preis" for="output-box">Price</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The labels should be in the same container as the inputs, not inside different `<div>` tags. There's no way to join them with flexbox if they don't share a container.

You could do it like this:

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="heading"> Taximeter</h1>
  <div class="inputBox">
    <label class="labels" id="km" for="input-box1">km</label>
    <input id="input-box1" class="box input" type="number" ...>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox">
    // another label + input
  </div>
  // some other label + input divs...
</div>
```

```css
.inputBox {
  display: flex;
}
```